# Perform custom update with MongoDB .Net (1.10)

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB .Net 1.10 with C#

I want to make a custom update in the same way that the mongo shell works.

For example, in the shell I can do the following:

```
db.myCollection.update({Name: "Test"}, {$set:{SomeProperty: "SomeValue"}})
```

Obviously I can do that in C# with:

```
myCollection.Update(Query.EQ("Name","Test"), Update.Set("SomeProperty", "SomeValue"));
```

The `Update()` function takes the arguments `IMongoQuery` and `IMongoUpdate`.
What I want to do is to make an update that would use `BsonDocument` as Query and `BsonDocument` as update.

=> `Update(BsonDocument value, BsonDocument update);`

I want this because I have alot of problems with the BsonSerializer which makes it very hard for me to do certain complex updates.

Now I looked up the two interfaces but they are empty. Therefore I can't create my own `IMongoQuery` and `IMongoUpdate` implementations (because there is nothing to implement).

So, is there any way I can call basic MongoDB function using BsonDocuments instead of the provided functions that force me to use the (not really well working) BsonSerializer and ClassMapper? Because they annoy the s*** out of me.

Bonus Question: What kind of alternative libraries are there for MongoDB .Net? i tried 2.0 and it forces `async` and generics on my in EVERY function which is unacceptable. And 1.10 can't even do the (in my opinion) most basic functions (passing BsonDocuments as arguments)

Comment: You don't need to use the `async` part of the 2.0 driver, just use the `.Result` or `.Wait` at the end of the method to force it to be synchronous. I'm not sure why you have a problem with the generics though...

Comment: @RonBeyer because I have types that are only known at runtime. These are also the reason why i have problems with the serializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these by accident (god bless IntelliSense).

There are two classes, `QueryDocument` and `UpdateDocument`, they are both simply extended `BsonDocument`s which implement the completely empty interfaces `IMongoQuery` and `IMongoUpdate`. They do have some additional (mostly deprecated) constructer overloads but no own properties or methods.
There is also `CommandDocument` which is the same thing for `IMongoCommand`.

So, by using them one can use any `BsonDocument` for update, query and other functions without limitations.

I really have to applaud the developers of the API on how they tried to hide these from the user. Instead of having an `Update(BsonDocument value, BsonDocument update);` function they created two empty interfaces and made two extend classes. Well Done!